# ClickOnce wrong Deployment url

Tags: clickonce

I have windows application that needs to be deployed via ClickOnce.
Publishing wizard creates install page that has wrong location of install files, and here is error log:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18408
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///D:/Download/My.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of D:\Download\My.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading file:///D:/Download/My.application did not succeed.
        + Could not find file 'D:\Download\My.application'.
        + Could not find file 'D:\Download\My.application'.
        + Could not find file 'D:\Download\My.application'.
```

publishing folder loc: 'd:\Projects\Setup\'
installation folder loc: '\mypc\d\Projects\Setup\'

So instead of looking for my app files in 'D:\Download' I need to change it to the folder where my setup files are 'd:\Projects\Setup\'

Where can I change it ?

Comment: have you ever set the path `'D:\Download\My.application'` in any step while deploy the application?

Comment: No I haven't that is strange thing

Comment: btw setup is running fine when I choose setup.exe from folder but error sows when I click Install button on install page

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue only when I use the "Install" button (the one that downloads setup.exe") in the generated page. Using the "Launch" (runs the .application) works fine in terms of finding and downloading the files. From what I can see, the issue is caused by downloading and then running the file. What I mean is that it seems to only work with a setup like IE or Edge, where it allows you to "run" the exe instead of saving it. Otherwise the deployment URL used by setup.exe will always be whatever directory you're running setup.exe from, i.e your downloads folder.